# Angular problem with loading facebook page in component

Tags: angular, facebook, plugins

I am trying to load Facebook plugin on my Angular 8 app in the home component. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

And for the first load home component everything works fine, but when I go to another route, and next go back to home the box of fb is empty.

[My fb box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2fVs.png)

The content does not appear again

```html
<div class="fb-page mx-auto border"
     data-href="https://www.facebook.com/tobagoaj/"
     data-tabs="timeline"
     data-width="500"
     data-height=""
     data-small-header="false"
     data-adapt-container-width="true"
     data-hide-cover="false"
     data-show-facepile="true">
  <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/tobagoaj/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tobagoaj/">Tobago - przyprawy i zioła</a>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Someone had similar problem, and could help me?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to manually initialize the FB page plugin.

This is to prevent any TS linting error while accessing window.FB

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        FB: any;
    }
}
```

Then check if `window.FB` exists, especially truthy when navigate away and come back using Angular routes.

```
if (window.FB && window.FB.init) {
  window.FB.init({ status: true, xfbml: true, version: 'v5.0' });
} else {
  // original FB SDK script login goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same situation with the facebook page plugin in one of my components - this solution worked for me:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var FB: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (FB != null && FB.XFBML != null)
      FB.XFBML.parse();
  }

}
```